# Flutter: showDatePicker: Is alternative text for cancel button possible?

Tags: flutter

I've got an app where the date field can be either a valid date or null. I find the showDatePicker description of "cancel" for the cancel button confusing. Just what does a user expect it to do? It could mean no change or it could mean no date. This is especially so in my case where I want it to mean "No Date". I've copied "date_picker.dart" and changed it to provide an optional alternative text for the "cancel" button.

I originally changed date_picker.dart to allow multiple buttons and clicking a button other than "ok" would return the text of the button. That however meant returning a var (dynamic), and I thought that's probably not acceptable. I then realised that just changing the text of the cancel button would suffice, and all that was required to change "date_picker.dart" was to provide an optional parameter for the alternative text in place of "cancel". There is only a few lines of code involved. The change is very simple. Clicking the cancel button returns null. Changing the text of the cancel button to "no date" will make the result obvious to the user.

If there is no way to achieve this without a program change, then I'll make a request for a change on Github.

Is there currently any way to achieve an alternative text for cancel button in showDatePicker / date_picker.dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`showDatePicker` presents a modal with the child being `_DatePickerDialog` class, which itself uses `localizations.cancelButtonLabel` for the Cancel button label.

We can override the `cancelButtonLabel` property by creating a custom localization delegate based on original English localization.

e.g. This is a delegate that returns default English localization except that `cancelButtonLabel` property is redefined:

```dart
class CancelButtonLocalizationDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> {
  const CancelButtonLocalizationDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => locale.languageCode == 'en';

  @override
  Future<MaterialLocalizations> load(Locale locale) => Future.value(CancelButtonLocalization());

  @override
  bool shouldReload(CancelButtonLocalizationDelegate old) => false;
}

class CancelButtonLocalization extends DefaultMaterialLocalizations {
  const CancelButtonLocalization();

  @override
  String get cancelButtonLabel => 'Custom Cancel';
}
```

Use `Localizations.override` to apply changes to the date picker child in the builder, e.g.

```dart
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  // ...,
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Localizations.override(
      context: context,
      delegates: [
        CancelButtonLocalizationDelegate(),
      ],
      child: child,
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Amazing. I would never have got that. It's a bit late here, I'll give it a tick tomorrow after I have another look at it.